# nuxt js, how can I get the host name of a web page at server side rendering

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

At nuxtjs poroject, I have a configure variable of api environment like this:

```
[
{
  front_host: local-1.domain.com,
  backend_api: api-1.domain.com
},
{
  front_host: local-2.domain.com,
  backend_api: api-2.domain.com
},
]
```

I need get the right object element from the host name, for example, if the host name of my web page is "local-1.domain.name", then I shall get the object `{front_host: local-1.domain.com, backend_api: api-2.domain.com}`.

In nuxtjs, if the web page renders at the front end, then I can get host name by `location.host`, if at ssr(server side rendering), how can I get the host name?

Comment: there are few functions like asyncData, fetch, nuxtServerInit , these methods get executed in server side. Also you can try using middleware too.

Answer (score 11):

Like@divine said, there are several options you could choose from.

For example,

```
export default {
     async asyncData ({ req, res }) {
        if (process.server) {
         return { host: req.headers.host }
        }
    }
```

host will be your ssr host name

Comment: Depending on your use-case it could error. Best to use something like: process.server ? req.headers.host : window.location.host

Answer (score 3):

in nuxt 3, you could also use:

```
const url = useRequestURL()
console.log('host name', url.hostname)
```

see: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-request-url

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work for you

```js
asyncData ({ req, res }) {
  const hostname = req ? req.headers.host : window.location.host.split(':')[0]
}
```